# SQL sum with dependency in other two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sum

I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | hear_about_us| bought_item_id             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     friend   | 1                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | internet     | 1                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | work         | 0                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | work         | 0                          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The real scenario is way more complicated so I simplified it.
I want to count everything depending on where the dudes came from.
so if I do

```
SELECT heard_about_us, SUM(bought_items) as sold FROM table GROUP BY heard_about_us
```

it counts this item twice, but it is the same item.

How can I sum the items bought according to the id of the buyer?

Thanks

Comment: Try `SELECT  DISTINCT heard_about_us, SUM(bought_items) as sold FROM table GROUP BY bought_item_id`

Comment: What results do you want?  What database are you using?  Only use the appropriate tag.  What column is the "id of the buyer"?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, SUM(bought_items) as sold FROM table GROUP BY id
```